# SharePoint 2019 eDiscovery with integration w/ Microsoft Exchange (everything on-premise)

Tags: sharepoint-search, exchange, ediscovery

We have SharePoint and Exchange **on-premise**. Via SharePoint, our Legal team would like to perform searches across our file shares, custom document stores and emails in Microsoft Exchange.

SharePoint is already crawling file shares and our various custom document shares. We don't currently have integration with Exchange.

Legal wants to be able to search for content and then export the search results (i.e. files) to a file share on the network, which they'll use for discovery purposes.

Does anyone have experience with SharePoint eDiscovery and integrating it with Microsoft Exchange? Does SharePoint eDiscovery support searching the contents of emails and attachments? And can we export those emails to a file share?

I would really like some feedback from someone with experience implementing and using SharePoint eDiscovery with result sources similar to our use case.

Comment: Any commentary on this, please?